# Upload image with soundcloud track API

Tags: curl, soundcloud

I would like to know if it is possible to upload an image when we use soundcloud API.

I tryed to pass some params as artwork_url without success following this method:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
           -F 'oauth_token=valid_token' \
           -F 'track[asset_data]=@audio.wav' \
           -F 'track[title]=A nice track title' \
           -F 'track[sharing]=public' \
           -F 'track[artwork_url]=@image.jpg'
```

I tried to upload a track from the soundcloud website with an attached image, works fine and the image is available in the `artwork_url` field.
Anyway trying to pass an image to this field while creating a new track with the API not working, without giving error.

I tried to pass URL also but with no luck.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the case you described that did work?

Comment: the case above works but no image is uploaded, if I want the image to show I have to upload my track from website, not with API.

Comment: you mentioned a case that "works fine" and "image is available" -- I meant that case. how are the two different, code-wise?

Comment: ok I found the problem, I have to use artwork_data params like this:

curl -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
           -F 'oauth_token=valid_token' \
           -F 'track[asset_data]=@audio.wav' \
           -F 'track[title]=A nice track title' \
           -F 'track[sharing]=public' \
           -F 'track[artwork_data]=@image.jpg'
Now all working fine.

Comment: why not add that as an answer formatted so it's easier to read

Comment: SO doesn't allow it to be well formated, I will be able to edit my question in 7 hours. sorry

Comment: oh, no problem -- I didn't realize there was a restriction.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming along, the answer was figured out in the comments section. That might not be obvious though, so here goes.

The problem here is that you're using the track[artwork_url] parameter, which is read-only. If you would like to upload artwork, use the track[artwork_data] parameter. Example:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
           -F 'oauth_token=valid_token' \
           -F 'track[asset_data]=@audio.wav' \
           -F 'track[title]=A nice track title' \
           -F 'track[sharing]=public' \
           -F 'track[artwork_data]=@image.jpg'
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://github.com/thomasmodeneis/soundcloudnodejs 
This is how you can upload a track with most used fields, including the image.

```
var track = {
 title: "My music",
 description: "My description",
 genre: "my genre",
 tag_list: "my tags with spaces",
 artwork_data: '/tmp/images/myimage.jpg',
 sharing: 'public',
 oauth_token: "MY_SOUNDCLOUD_TOKEN",
 asset_data: "/tmp/sound/mytrack.mp3",
};
```

Followed by the add method:

```
soundcloudnodejs.addTrack(track, function (err, track) {
...
 console.log("addTrack, track: ", track);
 console.log("permalink_url --> " + track.permalink_url);
});
```

Cheers.